# Update Total Price based on its Quantity with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm making a project where I have **Product Price**, **Quantity Form Field** and the **Total price**. I want the **Total price** to equal the multiplication of **Product Price** and **Quantity Form Field**. I want to perform this action with jQuery. I want that the **Total price** should change instantly with a change in its quantity.

All the PHP and CSS is already applied.

Here's my whole code!

```js
$('#quantity').on('keyup',function(){
    var tot = $('#price').val() * this.value;
    $('#total').val(tot);
});
```

```html
<form action="javascript:checkout()" id="theForm">
<div class="contains">
 <div class="head">Ticket cost includes <input id="quantity" class="quantity" type="number" value="1" name="quantity" min="1" max="6" /> persons.</div>
 <div class="facility">Meal <pre>X1</pre></div>
 <div class="facility">All Taxes <pre>X1</pre></div>
 <div class="facility">Whole Event <pre>X1</pre></div>
</div>
<div class="conclude">
 <div class="head">So what? Grab the Event at just $<span id="price" class="price"><?php echo $array['eventFees']; ?></span> per person.</div>
 <div class="pay-btn">Pay $<span id="total" class="total"><?php echo $array['eventFees']; ?></span></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Though I used the obvious jQuery, I got no result. The total price remained still. Please guide me further.

**Thanks in advance for the help.**

Comment: It depends on what the output of `$array['eventFees']` is. If it’s a formatted number, JavaScript may be having trouble parsing it. Check the console in a browser like Chrome to see any JavaScript errors.

Comment: @MartinBean It's not a formatted error

Comment: I don’t know that as I don’t know what `$array['eventFees']` contains, nor can I see your console to look at any errors.

Comment: `$array['eventFees']` contains a number from database. I have tried it by simply echoing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .text or .html to get/set the content of the span. It does not have value attribute that will display it. Also consider parsing the values to number to ensure proper calculation.

```js
$('#quantity').on('keyup',function(){
    var tot = parseInt($('#price').html()) * parseInt(this.value);
    $('#total').html(tot);
});
```

```html
<form action="javascript:checkout()" id="theForm">
<div class="contains">
 <div class="head">Ticket cost includes <input id="quantity" class="quantity" type="number" value="1" name="quantity" min="1" max="6" /> persons.</div>
 <div class="facility">Meal <pre>X1</pre></div>
 <div class="facility">All Taxes <pre>X1</pre></div>
 <div class="facility">Whole Event <pre>X1</pre></div>
</div>
<div class="conclude">
 <div class="head">So what? Grab the Event at just $<span id="price" class="price"><?php echo $array['eventFees']; ?></span> per person.</div>
 <div class="pay-btn">Pay $<span id="total" class="total"><?php echo $array['eventFees']; ?></span></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can check if the handler is executed by adding console.log(val) inside keyup event handler function

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using val() function and val() function only get value of input or select tags. Instead of val() function use html() or text() to grab the data.

Try this:

```
$('#quantity').on('keyup mouseup', function () {
    var tot = $.trim($('#price').html()) * this.value;
    $('#total').html(tot);
});
```

Comment: have you added mouseup event ?

Comment: You have used number type in input. When you increment it by 1 then mouseup event will be called and updated total span. keyup event only call when you are writing/inputting something in number textbox.

Comment: I have put example on jsbin. Can you please check http://output.jsbin.com/sozedukoho

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145449/discussion-between-dhaval-and-kumar-abhirup).